# Inkscape division action seems to shorten lines

Tags: vector, inkscape

I'm having issues with the Path Division tool. I have a shape which I would like to divide according to a set of combined paths, as seen below.

[image]

First, I select the path to split by, then the shape underneath (in this case the white continent). I then go to Path -> Division. However, the result is not as expected. I've shaded the regions to highlight the problem.

[image]

The lines seem to be shorter than they were drawn and are consequently not splitting properly. Does anyone know what the problem could be? All help is very appreciated.

Comment: Could you put the first SVG file somewhere so we could take a look? I can't reproduce this. You need to select your temporary "cutting" shape, then the shape to split one at a time. Is that what you did?

Answer (score 1):

**Inkscape definitely does not shorten lines**. I reconstructed your drawing and Inkscape properly splits the shape with combined paths:

[image]

Here is what almost certainly happened (of course without seeing your SVG I cannot be 100% sure): **Could it be that you had your line caps set to "Square cap" instead of "Butt cap"?**

[image]

In that case some of your drawn paths would appear to be overlapping at the end, but they're actually not:

[image]

When you combine the paths and do the division, you end up with the exact artifacts that you observed:

[image]